# python-snappy streaming data in a loop to a client

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, snappy

I would like to send multiple compressed arrays from a server to a client using [python snappy](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy), but I cannot get it to work after the first array. Here is a snippet for what is happening: 
(`sock` is just the network socket that these are communicating through)

Server:

```
for i in range(n): #number of arrays to send
    val = items[i][1] #this is the array
    y = (json.dumps(val)).encode('utf-8') 
    b = io.BytesIO(y)
    #snappy.stream_compress requires a file-like object as input, as far as I know.

    with b as in_file:
        with sock as out_file:
            snappy.stream_compress(in_file, out_file)
```

Client:

```
for i in range(n): #same n as before
    data = ''   
    b = io.BytesIO()
    #snappy.stream_decompress requires a file-like object to write o, as far as I know
    snappy.stream_decompress(sock, b)
    data = b.getvalue().decode('utf-8')

    val = json.loads(data)
```

`val = json.loads(data)` works only on the first iteration, but afterwards it stop working. When I do a `print(data)`, only the first iteration will print anything. I've verified that the server does flush and send all the data, so I believe it is a problem with how I  decide to receive the data.

I could not find a different way to do this. I searched and the only thing I could find is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711565/how-to-snappy-compress-a-file-using-a-python-script) which has led me to what I currently have.

Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` doesn't do what you think, refer to it's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). It calls `sock.__exit__()` after the block executed, that's not what you intended.

```
# what you wrote
with b as in_file:
    with sock as out_file:
        snappy.stream_compress(in_file, out_file)

# what you meant
snappy.stream_compress(b, sock)
```

**By the way:**

The line `data = ''` is obsolete because it's reassigned anyways.

Comment: When I change it to without using `with`, my client actually stops receiving data (with and without changing `json.dumps()` to `json.dump()`). It does not even receive the first array anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @paul-scharnofske's answer:

Likewise, on the receiving side: `stream_decompress` doesn't quit until end-of-file, which means it will read until the socket is closed. So if you send separate multiple compressed chunks, it will read all of them before finishing, which seems not what you intend. Bottom line, you need to add "framing" around each chunk so that you know on the receiving end when one ends and the next one starts. One way to do that... For each array to be sent:

- Create a `io.BytesIO` object with the json-encoded input as you're doing now
- Create a *second* `io.BytesIO` object for the compressed output
- Call `stream_compress` with the two `BytesIO` objects (you can `write` into a `BytesIO` in addition to reading from it)
- Obtain the `len` of the output object
- Send the length encoded as a 32-bit integer, say, with `struct.pack("!I", length)`
- Send the output object

On the receiving side, reverse the process. For each array:

- Read 4 bytes (the length)
- Create a `BytesIO` object. Receive exactly `length` bytes, writing those bytes to the object
- Create a second `BytesIO` object
- Pass the received object as input and the second object as output to `stream_decompress`
- json-decode the resulting output object

Comment: With your suggestion, the process no longer happens simultaneously. Originally, waiting for json to complete the `loads()` is still a bottleneck, but now I need to wait for the `stream_compress` to completely finish before I am able to `stream_decompress`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You could directly instantiate `StreamCompressor`, feed it chunks one by one and collect the output as it becomes available. Each time you reach some threshold (100KB, say). You send a block to the peer (prepended with a length and a continuation flag), at the end of an array, you send the last block, which would be smaller with continuation flag false. Then start the next array. On the receiving side, reverse the process, feeding chunks to `StreamDecompressor` as you receive them until you've processed the last (non-continued) one, at which point, you know you've got the entire json string.